# How to get network manager working with a wired connection in a new installation of Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, 22.04

```
nmcli con up Wired\ connection\ 1 
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection
(device eno1 not available because profile is not compatible with device (permanent MAC address doesn't match)).

$ ping google.com
PING google.com (142.251.33.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dfw25s44-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.33.14): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=28.9 ms
64 bytes from dfw25s44-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.33.14): icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=32.9 ms

$ ping -c4 archive.canonical.com
PING archive.canonical.com (185.125.188.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from canonical-archive-0.canonical.com (185.125.188.12): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=121 ms
64 bytes from canonical-archive-0.canonical.com (185.125.188.12): icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=122 ms

$ ping6 -c4 archive.canonical.com
$ ping6: connect: Network is unreachable
```

I tried `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` but it didn't solve the problem.

Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)

Answer (score 0):

```
nmcli con up Wired\ connection\ 1 
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection
(device eno1 not available because profile is not compatible with device (permanent MAC address doesn't match)).
```

The `ethernet.mac-address` property seems wrong.

Check the content of the profile with `nmcli connection show "$PROFILE"` or `nmcli -o connection show "$PROFILE"` -- where "$PROFILE" is `'Wired connection 1'`.

Then adjust `ethernet.mac-address` to a suitable value. Possibly, just unset it and set `connection.interface-name` instead.

`nmcli connection modify "Wired connection 1" ethernet.mac-address '' connection.interface-name eno1`.

Then reactivate the profile with `nmcli connection up Wired\ connection\ 1`.

See `man nm-settings` for the meaning of the properties of the connection profile.